# I have ListView Component in a js file and I want to use it another js file and show/hide the component on click of a button dynamically

Tags: react-native

How should i do it? My code is :

ListComponent.js

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
          AppRegistry,
          StyleSheet,
          Text,
          View,
          ListView,
          TouchableHighlight
        } from 'react-native';

        class ListComponent extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
              {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1!== r2});
            this.state = {
              dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(['A','B','C'])
            };
          }
          renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
            return (
              <TouchableHighlight
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.instructions}>{rowData}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            );
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
            );
          }
        }
        module.exports=ListComponent;
```

CreateMessage.js

```
        'use strict'
        var React= require('react');
        var ReactNative = require('react-native');
        var {
            View,
            Text,
            Image,
            StyleSheet,
            TouchableHighlight,
            TextInput,
            Dimensions,

        }= ReactNative;

        import { Container, Content, Picker } from 'native-base';

         var ListComp=require('./ListComponent');

         class CreateMessage extends React.Component{

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { email: 'Email ID' , pass:'Password',            name:'Name', isLoginClicked:'true',language:'ABC',pickerState:false};
      }
            press(){    
                this.setState({
                    pickerState : !this.state.pickerState
                     });
                }

 _renderList() {
 if (this.state.pickerState) {
return (
   <ListComp/>
    );
 } 
   else {
        return null;
         }
}

 render(){

 return (
  <View>
    <View>
     <View>
         <TouchableHighlight
         style={{flex:1}}>
        <Image 
         style={styles.headerImage}
         source={require('./images/back-arrow.png')}/>
         </TouchableHighlight>

        <Text> Create Message</Text>
  </View>
  <View>
    <TouchableHighlight>
    <Text>Done</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
    </View>
      <View>
       <Text>Post to</Text>

       <View>
          <View>
                    <Image 
                    style={{height:70,width:70,}}
                    source={require('./images/no-image.png')}/>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                    <Text 
                    style={styles.text}>name of community</Text>
                    <Text
                    style={styles.text1}>no. of members</Text>
                    </View>
 **<TouchableHighlight

                    underlayColor="gray"

                    onPress={this.press.bind(this)}>
                    <Image 
                    style={{height:20,width:20,}}
                    source={require('./images/add-button.png')}/>

                    </TouchableHighlight>**
  </View>
    <Text 
                    style={styles.headingText}>Subject</Text>

                    <TextInput></TextInput>

                    <Text 
                    style={styles.headingText}>Message</Text>

                    <TextInput></TextInput>
     <View>


         <TouchableHighlight}>
         <View>
         <Image 
         style={{height:20,width:20,marginLeft:0,}}
         source={require('./images/image-add-button.png')}/>

                    <Text>Add Photo</Text>
                    </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                    <Text>ADD PROJECT</Text>
                    </View>
                    </View>
                    </View>
          );
 }
 }
 module.exports=CreateMessage;
```

I am displaying CreateMessage.js in my index.ios.js file and it is working fine , but i want to show/hide a list on click of a button (3rd TochableHighlight ).

Comment: Call your `_renderList` function in render function

Comment: @Abhishek where in random function?

<TouchableHighlight

                    underlayColor="gray"
                    style={{flex:2,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}
                    onPress={this.press.bind(this)}>
                    <Image 
                    style={{height:20,width:20,}}
                    source={require('./images/add-button.png')}/>

                    </TouchableHighlight>
I want to show the list on click of this TouchableHighlight. How should I do that ? 
where should I call my renderList() ?

Comment: inside render function. And your code is not readable, format it.

Comment: @Abhishek where in random function? 

`<TouchableHighlight 
onPress={this.press.bind(this)}>
<Image
 source={require('./images/add-button.png')}/> 
</TouchableHighlight>`

 I want to show the list on click of this TouchableHighlight. How should I do that ? where should I call my renderList()' ?

Comment: Format your question properly, there is lot unnecessary whitespaces in code, remove styling part if possible. then we can help you. Otherwise its hard for us to understand the problem.

Comment: @Abhishek formatting of question is done now . 
Please see the code and help me because I am struck here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume `_renderList` is responsible for render your listview component. You can call it in render function.

```
render(){
 return (
  <View>
    {this._renderList()}
     /*......rest of your code....*/
  </View>
);
```